# jQuery tabs not hiding when file is hosted online

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have simple tabs that you can click between and view different content. Clicking hides all #tabs divs and then shows the one you clicked on. The javascript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');
    $('#tabs ul li a').click( 
        function(){ 
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); 
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="firstTab"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
      <li class="tabs"><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-2">
      <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-3">
      <h3>Tab 3</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-4">
      <h3>Tab 4</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
```

It works fine when the html file is on my hard drive and looks like this:

[image]

but when I put it on my Dropbox and open it they are all displayed under each other like this:

[image]

Note the same Dropbox-hosted file works fine in Firefox, and the local file on my hard drive works fine in BOTH Chrome and Firefox. It only happens when using Chrome to open the Dropbox-hosted file. The problem must arise from something to do with how Chrome handles files transferred with http versus local files and I dont know anything about that, so please any advice would be great

Comment: Can you post the dropbox URL?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40929021/site/index.html
it wont win any awards for design but i only just started it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript console has the following error:

> [blocked] The page at 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40929021/site/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Load the script with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

By leaving out the `http:` prefix, it will use the same protocol as the page.

Also, how about upgrading to a less prehistoric version of jQuery?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very inexperienced with programming and dont know much at all about web development (as you can see from the very basic page i posted) so I had no idea about this. As for the version of jQuery, I didn't write this javascript code and am only doing a simple page to host a couple portfolio items. Thanks again